# How to start an Activity depending on current situation when user taps on a notification?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications

Think on a project where your users can vote for a questions (like referendums does).

When a new question is available for vote, users will receive a new push notification, and when click on it, should opening, depending on the situation:

`Situation A`: Question is not voted, so app will open **VoteActivity** where users can vote.

`Situation B`: Question is already voted, so app will open **ResultsActivity** where users can check the results.

Since Intent is attached when notification is created, I am unable to recalculate what Intent should launch at this time.

What is the best approach to solve this?

**EDIT:**

I created the notification this way:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = null;


    try {
        notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this.context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_description_black_24dp)
                .setLargeIcon(getCircleBitmap(Picasso.with(this.context).load(pictureUrl).get()))
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setChannelId("contents")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: How do you create the notification? You can include a parameter there

Comment: Before to create the notification, check whether user already has voted or not and based on the result set corresponding `pendingIntent`

Comment: @AlexTa when user receive the notification, always will be `Situation A`. The point is, if the user entered the app using the icon on launcher instead of using the notification, the user can vote, and the notification will show again the `VoteActivity`.

Comment: @JuanCruzSoler I just updated my code showing how I am creating the notification.

Comment: Where do you create the pendingIntent? You can call the corresponding activity there